# King David’s mother

Tags: david, genealogy

“Turn to me and have mercy on me;
show your strength in behalf of your servant;
save me, because I serve you
just as my mother did.”
(Psalm 86, NIV)

**Is David’s mother *named* anywhere in the Bible?**

**She’s mentioned in Psalm 51; anywhere else?**

Comment: No, she is certainly not named in the Bible but *midrashim* name her as Nitzevet, as well as explaining why David was rejected by his brothers

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/theJewishWoman/article_cdo/aid/280331/jewish/Nitzevet-Mother-of-David.htm. Fascinating reading, though considering how many centuries it was written after the fact, I can't assume it's "gospel."  But most of it is quite believable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Psalm 69:8 — "I am become a stranger unto my brethren, and an alien unto my mother's children."

Psalm 51:5 — “Behold, I was brought forth in iniquity,
And in sin my mother conceived me”.

Psalm 116:16 — “I serve you just as my mother did”

1 Samuel 22:3 — “Will you let my father and mother stay with you?”

According to [GotQuestions:](https://www.gotquestions.org/David-mother.html)

> **The Bible does not mention King David’s mother by name.** A Jewish
> legend has named her Nitzevet, but there is no biblical confirmation
> of that name.

> **In Jewish tradition, David’s mother was Nitzevet, the daughter of
> Adael and the wife of Jesse.** **The Talmud relates a complicated story
> concerning Nitzevet**: her husband, Jesse, began to doubt the purity of
> his ancestry, since he was the grandson of Ruth the Moabitess (Ruth
> 4:17). Due to his doubts, Jesse stopped having marital relations with
> Nitzevet after she had borne her seventh son. Instead, Jesse planned
> to marry his Canaanite servant and have children with her. The
> maidservant, however, had pity on Nitzevet and offered Nitzevet a
> plan: on the wedding night, Nitzevet and the maidservant could
> secretly switch places, and Nitzevet could sleep with Jesse one more
> time. The switch worked, much as Leah and Rachel’s switch had worked
> on Jacob, and Nitzevet became pregnant with David, her eighth son.
> Nitzevet never revealed to Jesse what she had done, even when her
> pregnancy was apparent; therefore, Nitzevet came to be despised as an
> immoral woman, and her son, David, grew up an outcast in his own
> family. Again, this is an extrabiblical legend, and there is no way to
> confirm the accuracy of the tale of Nitzevet.
>
> These theories could explain why David was not accepted by his family:
> “I am a foreigner to my own family, a stranger to my own mother’s
> children” **(Psalm 69:8)**. David was left to tend the flocks when the
> prophet Samuel invited all of Jesse’s sons to a sacrifice (1 Samuel
> 16:5). God had told Samuel that He would choose one of the sons to be
> anointed king, but the family never even considered David as a
> possibility (1 Samuel 16:11). The theories might also shed some light
> on Psalm 51:5, “Behold, I was brought forth in iniquity, and in sin
> did my mother conceive me” (ESV).

According to [Good Question:](https://goodquestionblog.com/2023/04/02/who-was-king-davids-mother-and-how-many-children-did-she-have/)

> **The Bible actually does not tell us the name of David’s mother, but
> there is a Jewish tradition that her name was Nitzevet.** According to 1
> Chronicles, this woman had seven sons (Eliab, Abinadab, Shimea,
> Nethanel, Raddai, Ozem, and David) and at least two daughters (Zeruiah
> and Abigail).
>
> **There is some debate among biblical scholars as to whether Jesse was
> the father of Zeruiah and Abigail or whether their father was a man to
> whom Nitzevet was married before she married Jesse (she may have been
> widowed).** In 1 Chronicles, after the sons of Jesse are listed, Zeruiah
> and Abigail are called “their sisters” rather than “his daughters.”
> The sons of Zeruiah (Abishai, Joab, and Asahel) seem in the biblical
> narrative to be about the same age as David, even though he is their
> uncle. So Zeruiah may indeed have been many years older than David and
> she may have married and started to have children around the time he
> was born.

According to [Miriam Feinberg Vamosh](https://miriamfeinbergvamosh.com/king-davids-mother-she-stands-for-us/)

> **David was the great-grandson of the Moabite Ruth**, whose story we read
> on Shavuot and who famously joined her fate to the Israelites. But
> **Jesse, after years of marriage to the Israelite Nitzevet**, the mother
> of his seven sons, suddenly realized that as a prominent public
> figure, his part-Moabite status was an impediment.
>
> Jewish tradition accords Ruth high honors but the law in Deut. 23:3
> explicitly forbade intermarriage with Moabites. So, the sages said,
> Jesse felt compelled to cast Nitzevet out. This was for Nitzevet’s own
> good, they said – Jesse didn’t want to impugn Nitzevet’s status as the
> wife of a despised Moabite.
>
> The separation lasted for three years. Jesse became lonely and wanted
> more children. And so he took a Canaanite slave woman, who could
> provide him with a child of unquestionable lineage. This was possible,
> it was said, because if Jesse were to emancipate the slave, their
> children could be recognized as full-fledged members of the tribe.
>
> Compassion Births a Plan
>
> What an awkward, painful situation. Nitzevet and the slave woman,
> living alongside each other, meeting every day at the loom, the
> grinding stone or over the cooking fire, neither of them with any real
> way out. And then, out of compassion, the slave woman came up with a
> plan, using one of the few tools biblical women had: subterfuge. She
> would switch places with Nitzevet on Jesse’s sleeping pallet that
> night. This apparently worked well enough, because Nitzevet became
> pregnant.
>
> But from the moment her pregnancy began to show, Nitzevet’s own sons,
> ignorant of the bedroom switch, shunned and shamed her as an
> adulteress. The conscience-panged Jesse forbade his sons to harm her
> or the child, and eventually Nitzevet gave birth – to David. Jesse
> recognized the child as his own, although, like some biblical
> Cinderella, David was relegated to shepherd status, distanced from the
> family, a “stranger,” “hated without reason” (Psalm 69:4). Only
> twenty-eight years later – when Samuel the prophet anointed David king
> of Israel “in the midst of his brothers” (1 Samuel 16:12–13) – was the
> dignity of both mother and son restored. According to one source, it
> was at this point that Nitzevet uttered the words ascribed to David in
> Psalm 118: “The stone that the builders rejected….”

**In summary:** The Bible does not explicitly name David's mother, but there are Jewish traditions and legends regarding her identity. One tradition identifies her as Nitzevet, the wife of Jesse and the mother of David. According to these traditions, Nitzevet had several children, including David. There are debates among biblical scholars regarding the parentage of David's sisters, Zeruiah and Abigail, whether they were Jesse's daughters or from a previous marriage of Nitzevet.

Comment: chabad.org/theJewishWoman/article_cdo/aid/280331/jewish/…. says much the same.  Fascinating reading, though considering how many centuries it was written after the fact, I can't assume it's "gospel." But most of it is quite believable.

Answer (score 1):

@Jason gives a good answer to the main question. I would like to add that well known commentators doubt that this psalm was actually written by David himself.

[Keil & Delitzsch](https://www.studylight.org/commentaries/eng/kdo/psalms-86.html)

> It can only be called a Psalm by David as having grown out of Davidic
> and other model passages. The writer cannot be compared for poetical
> capability either with David or with the authors of such Psalms as Ps
> 116 and Psalms 130:1-8. His Psalm is more liturgic than purely poetic,
> and it is also only entitled תּפּלּה (Maskı̂l), without bearing in itself any
> sign of musical designation.

[Christian Hayes](https://oyc.yale.edu/religious-studies/rlst-145/lecture-21) of Yale University points out that despite the superscription of Psalm 86 attributing it to David:

> Book Two [of the Psalms] concludes with this postscript: “The prayers of David, the
> Son of Jesse, are ended.” (After Ps. 72) So at one time the Davidic
> Psalms were thought to end there... Nevertheless, tradition attributes the entire
> book of Psalms to King David and that attribution stems from the fact
> that 73 of the 150 Psalms are explicitly said to be psalms of David...
> The superscriptions, however, are in many cases late additions. So
> perhaps the Psalms can only be said to be of David or Davidic if by
> that term we mean that they are the result of a royal patronage of
> poetry by the House of David in general.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psalms#CITEREFBerlinBrettler2004) goes so far as to claim that "David's authorship is not accepted by most modern Bible scholars, who instead attribute the composition of the psalms to various authors writing between the 9th and 5th centuries BC." The claim that "the majority" think so is made without evidence. However, it is quite true that many scholars do doubt David's authorship, even of those psalms specifically ascribed to him.

**Conclusion**: The Bible does not identify King David's mother. Moreover, many scholars doubt whether this particular psalm was actually written by David in the first place.